# Jboss eap 6+ and maven repository run time reference location

Tags: maven, deployment, maven-2, jboss7.x, jboss-eap-6

I'm pretty new to Jboss eap 6+ and maven.
I have created a sample project using Jboss tool plug-in of eclipse and deployed via eclipse.
I didn't install maven separately, it came with above plug-in I guess.
As per my knowledge maven download all required JAR files that mentioned in .pom file in to local repository. In my case .m2\repository\ location.
But I don't understand how Jboss refer this location when it runs individually in a production server. There we don't have  any eclipse or jboss tool.
I checked .pom file in deployed project and still I didn't notice any location reference.
Technically I cannot understand how this works. It's really helpful if someone can explain bit further.
My question is, if I upload my project to a different Jboss in a different server, will it automatically down load all required JARs that mentioned in .pom file when deploying? If yes what is the location? How can I change that location?
What  is the exact procedure I have to follow when setup a production kind of environment (subject to maven repository)  ?
Just copy my Jboss along with deployed project to production environment, then can I expect Jboss and project .pom file take care of JARs and dependencies?
or  do I need to install and configure maven and repository in production environment?
What I understood may incorrect at all. It's really appreciate if you can help me on this.

Thanks

**Please find .pom file in deployed project.**

```
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/maven-v4_0_0.xsd">
    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>

    <groupId>org.jboss.tools.example.html5</groupId>
    <artifactId>jboss-as-kitchensink-html5-mobile</artifactId>
    <version>0.0.1-SNAPSHOT</version>
    <packaging>war</packaging>

    <name>jboss-as-kitchensink-html5-mobile</name>
    <description>A Java EE 6 HTML5 mobile web application for use with JBoss.</description>

    <url>http://jboss.org/aerogear</url>

    <properties>
        <!-- Explicitly declaring the source encoding eliminates the following message: -->
        <!-- [WARNING] Using platform encoding (UTF-8 actually) to copy filtered resources, i.e. build is platform dependent! -->
        <project.build.sourceEncoding>UTF-8</project.build.sourceEncoding>

        <!-- You can reference property in pom.xml or filtered resources (must enable third-party plugin if using Maven < 2.1) -->

        <!-- JBoss dependency versions -->

        <version.jboss.maven.plugin>7.4.Final</version.jboss.maven.plugin>
        <!-- Alternatively, comment out the above line, and un-comment the 
            line below to use version 7.2.0.Final-redhat-8 which is a release certified 
            to work with JBoss EAP 6. It requires you have access to the JBoss EAP 6 
            maven repository. -->
        <!-- <version.jboss.as>7.2.0.Final-redhat-8</version.jboss.as> -->

        <!-- Define the version of the JBoss BOMs we want to import to specify tested stacks. -->
        <version.jboss.bom>1.0.7.Final</version.jboss.bom>
        <!-- Alternatively, comment out the above line, and un-comment the line
            below to use version 1.0.4.Final-redhat-wfk-2 which is a release certified to
            work with JBoss EAP 6. It requires you have access to the JBoss EAP 6
            maven repository. -->
        <!-- <version.jboss.bom>1.0.4.Final-redhat-wfk-2</version.jboss.bom>> -->


        <!-- Other dependency versions -->
        <version.org.eclipse.m2e>1.0.0</version.org.eclipse.m2e>
        <version.ro.isdc.wro4j>1.4.4</version.ro.isdc.wro4j>

        <!-- other plugin versions -->
        <version.surefire.plugin>2.10</version.surefire.plugin>
        <version.war.plugin>2.2</version.war.plugin>

        <!-- maven-compiler-plugin -->
        <maven.compiler.target>1.6</maven.compiler.target>
        <maven.compiler.source>1.6</maven.compiler.source>
    </properties>

    <licenses>
        <license>
            <name>Apache License, Version 2.0</name>
            <distribution>repo</distribution>
            <url>http://www.apache.org/licenses/LICENSE-2.0.html</url>
        </license>
    </licenses>

    <dependencyManagement>
        <dependencies>
            <!-- JBoss distributes a complete set of Java EE 6 APIs including 
                a Bill of Materials (BOM). A BOM specifies the versions of a "stack" (or 
                a collection) of artifacts. We use this here so that we always get the correct 
                versions of artifacts. Here we use the jboss-javaee-6.0-with-tools stack 
                (you can read this as the JBoss stack of the Java EE 6 APIs, with some extras 
                tools for your project, such as Arquillian for testing) and the jboss-javaee-6.0-with-hibernate 
                stack you can read this as the JBoss stack of the Java EE 6 APIs, with extras 
                from the Hibernate family of projects) -->
            <dependency>
                <groupId>org.jboss.bom</groupId>
                <artifactId>jboss-javaee-6.0-with-tools</artifactId>
                <version>${version.jboss.bom}</version>
                <type>pom</type>
                <scope>import</scope>
            </dependency>
            <dependency>
                <groupId>org.jboss.bom</groupId>
                <artifactId>jboss-javaee-6.0-with-hibernate</artifactId>
                <version>${version.jboss.bom}</version>
                <type>pom</type>
                <scope>import</scope>
            </dependency>
        </dependencies>
    </dependencyManagement>

    <dependencies>
        <!-- First declare the APIs we depend on and need for compilation. All of them are provided by JBoss -->

        <!-- Import the CDI API, we use provided scope as the API is included in JBoss -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>javax.enterprise</groupId>
            <artifactId>cdi-api</artifactId>
            <scope>provided</scope>
        </dependency>

        <!-- Import the Common Annotations API (JSR-250), we use provided scope as the API is included in JBoss -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.jboss.spec.javax.annotation</groupId>
            <artifactId>jboss-annotations-api_1.1_spec</artifactId>
            <scope>provided</scope>
        </dependency>

        <!-- Import the JAX-RS API, we use provided scope as the API is included in JBoss -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.jboss.spec.javax.ws.rs</groupId>
            <artifactId>jboss-jaxrs-api_1.1_spec</artifactId>
            <scope>provided</scope>
        </dependency>

        <!-- Import the JPA API, we use provided scope as the API is included in JBoss -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.hibernate.javax.persistence</groupId>
            <artifactId>hibernate-jpa-2.0-api</artifactId>
            <scope>provided</scope>
        </dependency>

        <!-- Import the EJB API, we use provided scope as the API is included in JBoss -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.jboss.spec.javax.ejb</groupId>
            <artifactId>jboss-ejb-api_3.1_spec</artifactId>
            <scope>provided</scope>
        </dependency>

        <!-- Import the Servlet API, we use provided scope as the API is included in JBoss AS 7 -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.jboss.spec.javax.servlet</groupId>
            <artifactId>jboss-servlet-api_3.0_spec</artifactId>
            <scope>provided</scope>
        </dependency>

        <!-- JSR-303 (Bean Validation) Implementation -->
        <!-- Provides portable constraints such as @Email -->
        <!-- Hibernate Validator is shipped in JBoss -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.hibernate</groupId>
            <artifactId>hibernate-validator</artifactId>
            <scope>provided</scope>
            <exclusions>
                <exclusion>
                    <groupId>org.slf4j</groupId>
                    <artifactId>slf4j-api</artifactId>
                </exclusion>
            </exclusions>
        </dependency>

        <!-- Now we declare any tools needed -->

        <!-- Annotation processor to generate the JPA 2.0 metamodel classes for typesafe criteria queries -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.hibernate</groupId>
            <artifactId>hibernate-jpamodelgen</artifactId>
            <scope>provided</scope>
        </dependency>

        <!-- Needed for running tests (you may also use TestNG) -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>junit</groupId>
            <artifactId>junit</artifactId>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>

        <!-- Optional, but highly recommended -->
        <!-- Arquillian allows you to test enterprise code such as EJBs and Transactional(JTA) JPA from JUnit/TestNG -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.jboss.arquillian.junit</groupId>
            <artifactId>arquillian-junit-container</artifactId>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.jboss.arquillian.protocol</groupId>
            <artifactId>arquillian-protocol-servlet</artifactId>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>

    </dependencies>

    <build>
        <!-- Maven will append the version to the finalName (which is the name given to the generated war, and hence the context 
            root) -->
        <finalName>${project.artifactId}</finalName>
        <plugins>
            <plugin>
                <artifactId>maven-war-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>${version.war.plugin}</version>
                <configuration>
                    <!-- Java EE 6 doesn't require web.xml, Maven needs to catch up! -->
                    <failOnMissingWebXml>false</failOnMissingWebXml>
                </configuration>
            </plugin>
            <!-- The JBoss AS plugin deploys your war to a local JBoss AS container -->
            <!-- To use, run: mvn package jboss-as:deploy -->
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.jboss.as.plugins</groupId>
                <artifactId>jboss-as-maven-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>${version.jboss.maven.plugin}</version>
            </plugin>

        </plugins>
    </build>

    <profiles>
        <profile>
            <!-- The default profile skips all tests, though you can tune it to run just unit tests based on a custom pattern -->
            <!-- Seperate profiles are provided for running all tests, including Arquillian tests that execute in the specified container -->
            <id>default</id>
            <activation>
                <activeByDefault>true</activeByDefault>
            </activation>
            <build>
                <plugins>
                    <plugin>
                        <artifactId>maven-surefire-plugin</artifactId>
                        <version>${version.surefire.plugin}</version>
                        <configuration>
                            <skip>true</skip>
                        </configuration>
                    </plugin>
                </plugins>
            </build>
        </profile>
        <profile>
            <!-- When built in OpenShift the 'openshift' profile will be used when invoking mvn. -->
            <!-- Use this profile for any OpenShift specific customization your app will need. -->
            <!-- By default that is to put the resulting archive into the 'deployments' folder. -->
            <!-- http://maven.apache.org/guides/mini/guide-building-for-different-environments.html -->
            <id>openshift</id>
            <build>
                <plugins>
                    <plugin>
                        <artifactId>maven-war-plugin</artifactId>
                        <version>${version.war.plugin}</version>
                        <configuration>
                            <outputDirectory>deployments</outputDirectory>
                            <warName>ROOT</warName>
                        </configuration>
                    </plugin>
                </plugins>
            </build>
        </profile>
        <profile>
            <!-- Use this profile to use the wro4j plugin for validation, concatenation and -->
            <!-- minification of JavaScript and CSS files during the build -->
            <id>minify</id>
            <activation>
                <activeByDefault>false</activeByDefault>
            </activation>

            <build>
                <pluginManagement>
                    <plugins>
                        <!--This plugin's configuration is used to store Eclipse m2e settings only. It has no influence on the Maven build itself.-->
                        <plugin>
                            <groupId>org.eclipse.m2e</groupId>
                            <artifactId>lifecycle-mapping</artifactId>
                            <version>${version.org.eclipse.m2e}</version>
                            <configuration>
                                <lifecycleMappingMetadata>
                                    <pluginExecutions>
                                        <pluginExecution>
                                            <pluginExecutionFilter>
                                                <groupId>ro.isdc.wro4j</groupId>
                                                <artifactId>
                                                    wro4j-maven-plugin
                                                </artifactId>
                                                <version>${version.ro.isdc.wro4j}</version>
                                                <goals>
                                                    <goal>run</goal>
                                                </goals>
                                            </pluginExecutionFilter>
                                            <action>
                                                <ignore></ignore>
                                            </action>
                                        </pluginExecution>
                                    </pluginExecutions>
                                </lifecycleMappingMetadata>
                            </configuration>
                        </plugin>
                    </plugins>
                </pluginManagement>
                <plugins>
                    <plugin>
                        <groupId>ro.isdc.wro4j</groupId>
                        <artifactId>wro4j-maven-plugin</artifactId>
                        <version>${version.ro.isdc.wro4j}</version>
                        <executions>
                            <execution>
                                <phase>compile</phase>
                                <goals>
                                    <goal>run</goal>
                                </goals>
                            </execution>
                        </executions>
                        <configuration>
                            <targetGroups>app.min,m.screen.min,d.screen.min</targetGroups>
                            <cssDestinationFolder>${project.build.directory}/${project.build.finalName}/css/</cssDestinationFolder>
                            <jsDestinationFolder>${project.build.directory}/${project.build.finalName}/js/</jsDestinationFolder>
                            <wroManagerFactory>ro.isdc.wro.maven.plugin.manager.factory.ConfigurableWroManagerFactory</wroManagerFactory>
                        </configuration>
                    </plugin>
                    <plugin>
                        <artifactId>maven-surefire-plugin</artifactId>
                        <version>${version.surefire.plugin}</version>
                        <configuration>
                            <skip>true</skip>
                        </configuration>
                    </plugin>
                </plugins>
            </build>
        </profile>
        <profile>
            <!-- An optional Arquillian testing profile that executes tests in your JBoss AS instance -->
            <!-- This profile will start a new JBoss AS instance, and execute the test, shutting it down when done -->
            <!-- Run with: mvn clean test -Parq-jbossas-managed -->
            <id>arq-jbossas-managed</id>
            <dependencies>
                <dependency>
                    <groupId>org.jboss.as</groupId>
                    <artifactId>jboss-as-arquillian-container-managed</artifactId>
                    <scope>test</scope>
                </dependency>
            </dependencies>
        </profile>

        <profile>
            <!-- An optional Arquillian testing profile that executes tests in a remote JBoss AS instance -->
            <!-- Run with: mvn clean test -Parq-jbossas-remote -->
            <id>arq-jbossas-remote</id>
            <dependencies>
                <dependency>
                    <groupId>org.jboss.as</groupId>
                    <artifactId>jboss-as-arquillian-container-remote</artifactId>
                    <scope>test</scope>
                </dependency>
            </dependencies>
        </profile>

        <profile>
            <id>aerogearci-jbossas-managed-7</id>
            <dependencies>
                <dependency>
                    <groupId>org.jboss.as</groupId>
                    <artifactId>jboss-as-arquillian-container-managed</artifactId>
                    <scope>test</scope>
                </dependency>
            </dependencies>
            <build>
                <plugins>
                    <plugin>
                        <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
                        <artifactId>maven-surefire-plugin</artifactId>
                        <version>${version.surefire.plugin}</version>
                        <configuration>
                            <systemProperties>
                                <arquillian.launch>jbossci</arquillian.launch>
                                <arquillian.jboss_home>${project.build.directory}/jboss-as-${version.jboss.as}/
                                </arquillian.jboss_home>
                            </systemProperties>
                            <includes>
                                <include>**/*.java</include>
                            </includes>
                        </configuration>
                    </plugin>
                    <plugin>
                        <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
                        <artifactId>maven-dependency-plugin</artifactId>
                        <executions>
                            <execution>
                                <id>unpack-as7</id>
                                <phase>process-test-classes</phase>
                                <goals>
                                    <goal>unpack</goal>
                                </goals>
                                <configuration>
                                    <artifactItems>
                                        <artifactItem>
                                            <groupId>org.jboss.as</groupId>
                                            <artifactId>jboss-as-dist</artifactId>
                                            <version>${version.jboss.as}</version>
                                            <outputDirectory>${project.build.directory}</outputDirectory>
                                            <type>zip</type>
                                            <overWrite>false</overWrite>
                                        </artifactItem>
                                    </artifactItems>
                                </configuration>
                            </execution>
                        </executions>
                    </plugin>
                </plugins>
            </build>
        </profile>
    </profiles>

</project>
```

Comment: Please let me know if this question not clear, then I'll try to clarify more  -Thanks

Comment: I'm still waiting for an answer.... :(

Answer (score 2, accepted):

JBoss doesn't download or try to find any of your app declared dependencies outside your application or outside its modules or lib.

That's a 10000-foot view of how maven packages you WAR or EAR:

- first it looks if a declared dependency is already at your local repository
- second if it is not, it tries to download each declared dependency from the maven central repository, then if it is not there it tries to download from any active repository declared in your pom.xml and in your settings.xml
- any time it downloads a dependency it parses its pom.xml and recursively downloads its dependencies using the same procedure described in the first and second steps
- after maven downloads the dependencies, it uses javac to compile you project and puts every dependency declared as "compile dependency" somewhere into the target directory so when it packages your project, the compile dependencies will be **inside** your package. Note that if you don't declare the type of dependency you have it wil default to "compile dependency"
- no dependencies declared as runtime or provided will be packaged within your application and must be present in a jboss module or the jboss lib or your application won't deploy correctly.

Of course this 10000-foot view of how maven packages a WAR or EAR doesn't describe any of the 17 phases of package build lifecycle in detail. A good reference to the build lifecycle is at http://maven.apache.org/guides/introduction/introduction-to-the-lifecycle.html, and good introduction to dependency mechanism is at http://maven.apache.org/guides/introduction/introduction-to-dependency-mechanism.html and http://maven.apache.org/guides/introduction/introduction-to-optional-and-excludes-dependencies.html